# mfmailcomposer to attach a pdf to an email doesnt work with ipad 1 but ok with ipad2

Tags: pdf, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using the code below to download a pdf file from a website and subsequently to display it in a uiwebview

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString:[[[popOverContent currentValues]     objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Web"]];

    // Determile cache file path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.pdf"];

    // Download and write to file
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    fileToAtatch = urlData;

    // Load file in UIWebView
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

all works as expected at this point but later when i use the following code to atatch the pdf file to an email using mfmailcomposer i get problems.

```
-(IBAction)EmailPressed:(id)sender
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSString *query = @"please find atatched the requested data sheet";
    [viewController setSubject:[popOverContent selectedSize]];
    [viewController setMessageBody:query isHTML:NO];
    [viewController addAttachmentData:fileToAtatch mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[popOverContent selectedSize]];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

}

this code works exactly as expected and the multi page pdf attaches as expected.

if i test the app on iPad with ios 5.0.1 sending the email to myself, when i click on the icon for the pdf in the email, the pdf doesn't open, and the preview just sits there with a uiprogress indicator spinning.
however if i test the app in the same way on an ipad2 with ios 6.0.1 the pdf file opens with no problems.
it also works on iphone 5 and also on mac with mountain lion.

so whats happening?
can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code and implementation to give me this strange behaviour on ipad 1 but not on ipad 2 etc.

please advise

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure this out and solved the problem by changing my code as follows

```
         fileName = [selectedSizeToUse stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"];
         [mailController setSubject:selectedSizeToUse];
         [mailController addAttachmentData:fileToAtatch mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
```

seems that for ios5 implementations pdf files need the .pdf extension to be recognised in the preview application, while in iOS 6 implementations the preview app was clever enough to display the pdf without the .pdf extension.

hope this helps somebody else that got stuck